# Split count based on group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help to create split rows based group by count & if count more than 1000, example below

Table 1 (Some sequential data with unique Id)

```
AID Batchid Status
1   PWB   0
1   PWB   0
1   PWB   0
1   PWB   0
2   PWB   0
2   PWB   0
2   PWB   0


CREATE TABLE #Tmp(
AID VARCHAR(5),
Tnt FLOAT,
BatchId VARCHAR(20),
status INT)
INSERT INTO #Tmp
SELECT  distinct AID, count(*),'PWB',0  FROM table1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
GROUP BY AID
SELECT * FROM #Tmp
DROP TABLE #Tmp
```

Above Query Output is

```
AID Tnt BatchId status
0   20    PWB   0
1   1     PWB   0
42  5010  PWB   0
11  2     PWB   0
```

But I want & first column will be unique to split the rows

```
AID Tnt BatchId status
0   20    PWB   0
1   1     PWB   0
42  1000  PWB   0
42  1000  PWB   0
42  1000  PWB   0
42  1000  PWB   0
42  1000  PWB   0
42  10    PWB   0
11  2     PWB   0
```

Comment: Provide some sample data from table1 so that it will be more clear to understand the requirement.

Comment: From the table 1 I have made group by AID take the over all count

Comment: What is 1000 and where it comes from?

Comment: 1000 is predefined count of each row on the first table count is 5010 & I need split up 1000 each

Answer (score 0):

CROSS APPLY tally table. I use sys.all_objects as a tally. Note Tnt must be `int`, no reason to declare count(*) as `float`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp(
  AID VARCHAR(5),
  Tnt Int,
  BatchId VARCHAR(20),
  status INT);

-- your sample data
INSERT INTO #Tmp
VALUES
 (0  ,20   ,'PWB',0)
,(1  ,1    ,'PWB',0)
,(42 ,5010 ,'PWB',0)
,(11 ,2    ,'PWB',0);

--parameter
DECLARE @limit int = 1000;
SELECT AID, CASE WHEN rn*@limit <= Tnt THEN @limit ELSE Tnt%@limit END as Tnt, BatchId, status
FROM #Tmp t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(Tnt/@limit + CASE Tnt%@limit WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tnt)
    FROM sys.all_objects
) x;

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks. Count(*) is used to take total count of table1

Comment: You may accept the answer if it works, it's SO way of saying thanks :)  . Otherwise comment on problems with the answer.

Comment: Just wondering: you are using `Int` for `Tnt` while the original post suggests `float`. Not sure if this is important for the OP but in that case your solution won't work anymore. Especially the `%` (modulo) would have to be rewritten as this does not work with `float`.

Comment: @Ralph, you are right and I pointed it out in my answer that `Tnt` must be `int` in `#tmp`, which is just a temp table. No reason to choose `float` just to store `count(*)` data.